# Woocommerce: Как добавить баннер в список продуктов

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Доброго дня!

Задача такая: необходимо добавить баннер в список товаров между произвольными товарами.

Предполагаю что должен быть некий хук, но добыть информацию не удаётся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет такого хука - между продуктами. Вам нужно скопировать файл `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php` в папку `/wp-content/themes/моя_тема/woocommerce/archive-product.php` и править его. Там содержится вывод основного цикла по товарам.